# Shopping Cart in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net

i have an e-commerce web site so i have problem about shopping cart. When i remove product, shopping cart dropdown box disappear. How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

```
.block-minicart > .dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: .35s;
    -o-transition: .35s;
    transition: .35s;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 7px 0 rgba(50,50,50,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 7px 0 rgba(50,50,50,.2);
    color: #666;
}
```

Comment: it may have so many reason and you have not posted your question clearly. how you are adding to and put that cart value?

Comment: Can you provide us add to shopping cart button code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `Remove()`(or an equivalent) method and it makes a call to your server to remove an item that's added to the cart, the following should work for you.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
    var ui = parseInt($(this).attr('data-product-id'));
    Sad.Cart.Remove(1, ui);
});
```